# Detecting a collection-type property on a .NET object using reflection

Tags: .net, object, reflection, collections

I am trying to write some code that would iterate over my business objects and dump out their contents into a log file.

For that, I'd like to be able to find all public properties and output their name and value using reflection - and I'd also like to be able to detect **collection properties** and iterate over those, too.

Assuming two classes like this:

```
public class Person 
{
    private List<Address> _addresses = new List<Address>(); 

    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public List<Address> Addresses
    {
        get { return _addresses; }
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

I currently have code something like this which finds all public properties:

```
public void Process(object businessObject)
{
    // fetch info about all public properties
    List<PropertyInfo> propInfoList = new List<PropertyInfo>(businessObject.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public));

    foreach (PropertyInfo info in propInfoList)
    {
       // how can I detect here that "Addresses" is a collection of "Address" items 
       // and then iterate over those values as a "list of subentities" here?
       Console.WriteLine("Name '{0}'; Value '{1}'", info.Name, info.GetValue(businessObject, null));
    }
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to detect that a given property (e.g. the `Addresses` on the `Person` class) is a **collection of `Address` objects**? Can't seem to find a `propInfo.PropertyType.IsCollectionType` property (or something similar that would give me the info I'm looking for)

I've (unsuccessfully) tried things like:

```
info.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEnumerable))
info.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<>))

info.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable))
```

Comment: Marc, did you get it to work or do you need any further information?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: no, it seems your answer really covers it. Works for me. Thanks. Sorry for forgetting to accept earlier....

Comment: Not a problem. Just wanted to make sure you got everything you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check for [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) which is implemented by every single collection, even by arrays:

```
var isCollection = info.PropertyType.GetInterfaces()
                       .Any(x => x == typeof(IEnumerable));
```

Please note that you might want to add some special case handling for classes that implement this interface but that should still not be treated like a collection. [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) would be such a case.

Comment: Why not `typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(info.PropertyType)` or `info.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable))`? (I lean towards the former but haven't verified the value for an unboxed value type that implements `IEnumerable`, such as [`ArraySegment<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Would be possible, too. What you are seeing in my answer is just the first that came to my mind.

Comment: doesn't this match the string properties too?

Comment: @AnthonyJohnston: Correct. See the last paragraph of my answer ;)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth fair enough - glasses on :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the hassle with strings and other things:

```
    var isCollection = info.PropertyType.IsClass && 
info.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable));
```